# How to disable popover when I dragging event?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

How can I hide popover element when I start dragging event in fullcalendar and after stop dragging show popover again?

I have this code:

```
eventRender: function(event, elementos, resource, view) {
        var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "DD-MM-Y HH:mm");
        var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "DD-MM-Y HH:mm");
        elementos.popover({
          title: start + ' — ' + end,
          content: event.title,
          trigger: 'hover',
          placement: 'top',
          container: 'body'
        });
      }
```

And when I want to resize or dragging event this happend:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer you think it's right. We are expecting this from you. Don't just ask and go away.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `eventAfterRender` instead of `eventRender` function to achieve the desired result. So your code will look like this:

```
  eventAfterRender: function(event, elementos, resource, view) {
    // code goes here
  }
```

This works because `eventRender` is constantly called while dragging because the event is constantly being "snapped" into a cell (in non-month views) and hence ends up creating all the popovers, while `eventAfterRender` is triggered after an event has been placed on the calendar in its final position.

You can see it in action [here in this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XBeGjL?editors=0010)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.
Based on Taha code, here is a ready-to-use code for those wondering how to do it with Fullcalendar :

```
eventDragStart: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
  window.eventScrolling = true;
},
eventDragStop: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
  window.eventScrolling = false;
},
eventRender: (event, elementos, resource, view) {
    if(window.eventScrolling) return;
    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "DD-MM-Y HH:mm");
    var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "DD-MM-Y HH:mm");
    elementos.popover({
      title: start + ' — ' + end,
      content: event.title,
      trigger: 'hover',
      placement: 'top',
      container: 'body'
    });
  }
},
eventResize: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
  $(".popover").remove();
},
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to put $ (". Popover"). Remove (); before the element.popover. Like this.

```
eventRender: function(event, element, resource, view) {

       $(".popover").remove();

var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "DD-MM-Y HH:mm");
var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "DD-MM-Y HH:mm");
element.popover({
    title: start + ' — ' + end,
    content: event.title,
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'top',
    container: 'body',
      live: true,
            html: true,
            placement: 'above'
});
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Marcelo Codo, this worked for me. fullcalendar v4

```
$('.popover').remove();
$(info.el).popover({ title: 'ddd', placement:'top', trigger : 'hover', content: tooltip, container:'body' }).popover('show');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a flag to the scroll event that the popover shouldn't render.

pseudocode:

```
$("element").on("dragstart", function(){
   window.eventScrolling = true;
});

$("element").on("dragend", function(){
   window.eventScrolling = false;
});
eventRender: function(event, elementos, resource, view) {
    if(window.eventScrolling) return;
    var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "DD-MM-Y HH:mm");
    var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "DD-MM-Y HH:mm");
    elementos.popover({
        title: start + ' — ' + end,
        content: event.title,
        trigger: 'hover',
        placement: 'top',
        container: 'body'
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! 
Fullcalendar has triggers `eventDragStart` and `eventDragStop`. Can I add this code to this triggers ?

Comment: I won't downvote since you put the OP on the right track, but `eventRender` fires only the first time each event is appended to DOM, so on creation or after drag end

Comment: @Yuri yes it was a psydocode, to tell OP the logic. I didn't care much about the event because I don't know much about fullcalendar and it's events.

Comment: @AlexanderFrolov I don't know much about the events but yes they seem to be the right ones.